# how to insert array into database in laravel without error

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel

I have an excel file , i build an array from excel and I need insert array to database in laravel but laravel have error my array is

```
private function InsertInDatabase(): void
{
    $insertableData = [
        ['name' => 'joe', 'card_type' => 'mastercard', 'balance' => 100 , 'last_ip'=> '122.154.1.5'],
        ['name' => 'sara', 'card_type' => 'visa', 'balance' => 10 , 'last_ip'=> '125.194.11.150'],
    ];
        
    $arrayCount = count($insertableData);

    for ( $l = 0; $l <= $arrayCount; $l++ )
    {

        
        Database::table($this->dbname)->insert(
            $insertableData[$l]
        );
        
            
    }
}
```

but have error how I can clear this error

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\xlsfile\app\Excel\ExcelToDatabase.php on line 99
```

Comment: What is `$arraylist` ? Where was it declared ?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you show us how you build the array from Excel?

Comment: sorry I can not show main excel data

Answer (score 0):

$arraylist[$l] must be $insertableData[$l]

or use Bulk insert:

Model::insert($insertableData);

Comment: Better use bulk insert:
Model::insert($data);

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$data = [
    [...], [...]
]

foreach($data as $item) {
     YourModel::create($item); // YourModel::insert($item);
     //Database::table($this->dbname)->insert($item);
}
```

Or Bulk insert

```
YourModel::insert($data); <-- Eloquent
// DB::table($this->dbname)->insert($data); <-- Query Builder
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no`$arraylist` variable in the code. I think you meant `$insertableData`. If yes, replace `$arraylist` by `$insertableData`.

---

you don't actually need the loop:

```
$insertableData = [
        ['name' => 'joe', 'card_type' => 'mastercard', 'balance' => 100 , 'last_ip'=> '122.154.1.5'],
        ['name' => 'sara', 'card_type' => 'visa', 'balance' => 10 , 'last_ip'=> '125.194.11.150'],
    ];

DB::table($this->dbname)->insert($insertableData);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to do a bulk insert in Laravel using Eloquent or the query builder.

You can use the following approach.

```
 $data = [
        ['user_id'=>'Coder 1', 'subject_id'=> 4096],
        ['user_id'=>'Coder 2', 'subject_id'=> 2048],
        //...
    ];

    Model::insert($data); // Eloquent approach
    DB::table('table')->insert($data); // Query Builder approach
```